# downloading to usb

Tags: usb, cd, downloads

I downloaded the program and clicked on the option to download it to a usb drive but once downloaded it prompted that I burn it to a CD but my netbook doesn't have a CD-ROM. Suggestions?

Comment: What's 'the program'? If its Ubuntu, and you would like to make a usb installer, go to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download and have a look at step two.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a step on the [Download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) Select 'USB stick' and your current OS in step 2, then hit the 'Show me how' button.

[image]